# Ping to localhost system

Tags: sockets, unix, tcp, ping, latency

I have multiples server with the same configuration. I am trying to ping localhost 127.0.0.1 from each servers. I am getting different response from one of the server. 
I get mostly following result from all the servers except one.

```
--- 127.0.0.1 ping statistics ---
19 packets transmitted, 19 received, 0% packet loss, time 18000ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.003/0.004/0.011/0.002 ms
```

The problem is , from one of the server I get following results.

```
PING 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.007 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.006 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.006 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.006 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.006 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=0.006 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=7 ttl=64 time=0.006 ms    
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=8 ttl=64 time=0.006 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=9 ttl=64 time=0.018 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=10 ttl=64 time=0.018 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=11 ttl=64 time=0.018 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=12 ttl=64 time=0.019 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=13 ttl=64 time=0.018 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=14 ttl=64 time=0.018 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=15 ttl=64 time=0.018 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=16 ttl=64 time=0.018 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=17 ttl=64 time=0.018 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=18 ttl=64 time=0.019 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=19 ttl=64 time=0.018 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=20 ttl=64 time=0.018 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=21 ttl=64 time=0.018 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=22 ttl=64 time=0.018 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=23 ttl=64 time=0.031 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=24 ttl=64 time=0.018 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=25 ttl=64 time=0.018 ms

--- 127.0.0.1 ping statistics ---
25 packets transmitted, 25 received, 0% packet loss, time 23999ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.006/0.014/0.031/0.008 ms
```

My /etc/hosts file have following line
    127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain localhost

Could you please advise what could be wrong here?

[update from commets:]

My worry is avg time per packet, that is too high in second case.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong.  All your packets still get through in both cases ("0% packet loss").  You're just getting more detailed output in the second case, with one line per packet (unless you're also getting that in the first case and you're just omitting it".  There's just a slight difference in your settings or your operating system version.

Comment: Yes, I am getting detailed output with one line packet in first case also. Sorry, I omitted it. My worry is avg time per packet, that is too high in second case.

Comment: Most likely that machine is slower for some reason - less processing, less memory, more other stuff running on it, disk is fuller, or whatever.  Given the difference is in the microsecond range, it's likely to be swamped by network latency once you are using an actual network.